# Flag tukey outliers using python pandas groupby

Tags: python, beginner, pandas

I'm new to python and pandas.

I would like to use pandas `groupby()` to flag values in a df that are outliers. I think I've got it working, but as I'm new to python, wanted to ask if there is a more obvious / pythonic approach.

Given input data with two groups, two variables X and Y:

```
n=10000
df= pd.DataFrame({'key': ['a']*n+['b']*n
                 ,"x"  : np.hstack((
                  np.random.normal(10, 1.0, size=n)
                 ,np.random.normal(100, 1.0, size=n)
                  ))
                 ,"y"  : np.hstack((
                  np.random.normal(20, 1.0, size=n)
                 ,np.random.normal(200, 1.0, size=n)
                  ))              
                 })
```

To identify outliers I need to calculate the quartiles and inter-quartile range for each group to calculate the limits.  Seemed reasonable to create a function:

```
def get_outlier(x,tukeymultiplier=2):
    Q1=x.quantile(.25)
    Q3=x.quantile(.75)
    IQR=Q3-Q1
    lowerlimit = Q1 - tukeymultiplier*IQR
    upperlimit = Q3 + tukeymultiplier*IQR
    return (x<lowerlimit) | (x>upperlimit)
```

And then use `groupby()` and call the function via transform, e.g.:

```
g=df.groupby('key')[['x','y']]
df['x_outlierflag']=g.x.transform(get_outlier)
df['y_outlierflag']=g.y.transform(get_outlier)

df.loc[df.x_outlierflag==True]
df.loc[df.y_outlierflag==True]
```

I'm not worried about performance at this point, because the data are small.  But not sure if there is a more natural way to do this?  For example, it's not clear to me how apply() differs from transform().  Is there an `apply()` approach that would be better?

Is this approach reasonably pythonic / in line with best practices?  I would like to stick with pandas.  I realize there are SQL approaches etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding a thousands-separator to `10_000`.

When generating random sample data for this kind of application, always set a constant seed.

There's a lot of formatting here that's non-standard; run a PEP8 linter and/or use PyCharm. The only thing I'll call out specifically is leading commas like

```
,"y"  : np.hstack((
```

Aside from being non-PEP8-compliant, it's just not legible.

Your use of `groupby` didn't actually work for me (different version of Pandas?), but your `[['x', 'y']]` just doesn't make sense since you re-index for those column names again later. You can just delete that index operation.

Don't `transform` on a custom function if you can avoid it; it breaks vectorisation. Instead, `transform` on only `quantile` which is built into Pandas and should run more quickly; this also means you don't have to write your own inner function.

Don't mutate a function argument in-place if you can avoid it.

Don't operate on `x` and `y` specifically. For this application, just broadcast to all non-key columns.

### Suggested

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng


def flag_outliers(df: pd.DataFrame, tukey_multiplier: float = 2) -> pd.DataFrame:
    data_cols = df.columns[df.columns != 'key']
    groups = df.groupby('key')

    q1 = groups.transform('quantile', .25)
    q3 = groups.transform('quantile', .75)
    iqr = q3 - q1
    lower_limit = q1 - tukey_multiplier*iqr
    upper_limit = q3 + tukey_multiplier*iqr

    is_outlier = (df[data_cols] < lower_limit) | (df[data_cols] > upper_limit)
    is_outlier.columns = data_cols + '_outlier_flag'
    return is_outlier


def test() -> None:
    n = 10_000
    rand = default_rng(seed=0)
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'key': ['a']*n + ['b']*n,
        'x': np.hstack((
            rand.normal(10, 1.0, size=n),
            rand.normal(100, 1.0, size=n),
        )),
        'y': np.hstack((
            rand.normal(20, 1.0, size=n),
            rand.normal(200, 1.0, size=n),
        )),
    })
    outliers = flag_outliers(df)
    # optionally pd.concat() outliers to df
    print(outliers)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a lot there for me to learn.  I'm a fan of the leading comma from SQL.  But helpful to see that the extra trailing commas don't cause problems.  And your indenting is better.  Can you explain where I mutated a function argument in-place? I used `[['x','y']]` on my groupby because the data frame has some non-numeric columns.  Maybe in your approach, I should use `data_cols = df.drop(columns='key').select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns` ?

Comment: _where I mutated a function argument in-place_ - `df['x_outlierflag']=` (assuming that's in a function, which it should be). Or interpreted differently, you didn't mutate an input, but you also didn't capture enough of your code in a function.

Comment: _I used [['x','y']] on my groupby because the data frame has some non-numeric columns_ - fine; but you should do that before your group operation, i.e. before passing the frame to the function. Preferably that instead of `select_dtypes`.